# ASP.NET MVC, lambda and performance

Tags: asp.net-mvc, performance, caching, reflection, lambda

In MVC flavor of ASP.NET, I'm wondering what is the cost of relying on lambda expressions and data annotations as implied by the use of EditorFor and other *For helpers.
I suppose all is stuff is cached - am I correct?

Any link or explanation on this topic is welcome.

Thank you!

Side question: Are there coding practices to avoid because it would prevent a proper caching?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The corresponding view is indeed cached. However, as far as I can see, it is still being rendered every time it is called.

You can trace this down in System.Web.Mvc.Html.TemplateHelper.cs (source code available on the ASP.NET codeplex site: http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they're cached. As for coding practices...don't think so.